# Xtext hyperlinking how to?

Tags: xtext

I would like to create hyperlink custom processing in the my project but can't found any examples or tutorials.

May I ask you to give me the link on some example,or tutorials?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: can you be more specific on what kind of customization of hyperlinking you want to apply. the code of HyperlinkHelper isnt that complicated to customize. but without any requirements it is hard to point into directions

Comment: I woud like do do following: my grammar is a set of links on another files. I woud like to add ctrl+click functionality. I.e. when I ctrl+click(or press f3) on the link editor will open linked file.
Regards, Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

If other files are backed up by EMF resources then you can index them with Xtext, particularly index EMF objects which uniquely identify resources, and then add references to them in your grammar.

As an alternative you can customize `HyperlinkHelper` as Christian suggested. The issue is that you have to customize all UI components where notions of such references should be present, e.g. find references. You don't have this issue if you explicitly model your references as I've mentioned above.

Comment: I know about HyperlinkHelper customizing, but woud like to get example of it. Or, maybe tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I have the ansver.
To do this we need just override method

```
def Class<? extends DefaultHyperlinkDetector> bindDefaultHyperlinkDetector()
```

of the class

```
AbstractMyDslUiModule
```

Will do it in following way

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.9.2
 */
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui

import org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.FinalFieldsConstructor
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.hyperlinking.DefaultHyperlinkDetector

/**
 * Use this class to register components to be used within the Eclipse IDE.
 */
@FinalFieldsConstructor
class MyDslUiModule extends AbstractMyDslUiModule {
    def Class<? extends DefaultHyperlinkDetector> bindDefaultHyperlinkDetector() {
        return MyHyperlinkDetector;
    }
}
```

Than I need to override class **DefaultHyperlinkDetector**

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IRegion;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Region;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlink;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.hyperlinking.DefaultHyperlinkDetector;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.hyperlinking.IHyperlinkHelper;

public class MyHyperlinkDetector extends DefaultHyperlinkDetector{
    private static final String PREFERENCES = "Hello";

    @Override
    public IHyperlink[] detectHyperlinks(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion region, boolean canShowMultipleHyperlinks) {
        IDocument document = textViewer.getDocument();
          int offset = region.getOffset();

          // extract relevant characters
          IRegion lineRegion;
          String candidate;
          try {
           lineRegion = document.getLineInformationOfOffset(offset);
           candidate = document.get(lineRegion.getOffset(), lineRegion.getLength());
          } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
           return null;
          }

          // look for keyword
          int index = candidate.indexOf(PREFERENCES);
          if (index != -1) {

           // detect region containing keyword
           IRegion targetRegion = new Region(lineRegion.getOffset() + index, PREFERENCES.length());
           if ((targetRegion.getOffset() <= offset) && ((targetRegion.getOffset() + targetRegion.getLength()) > offset))
            // create link
            return new IHyperlink[] { new PreferencesHyperlink(targetRegion) };
          }

          return null;
    }

}
```

And next we need to implement IHyperlink interface **IHyperlink**

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.IRegion;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlink;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil;

public class PreferencesHyperlink implements IHyperlink {

    private final IRegion fUrlRegion;

    public PreferencesHyperlink(IRegion urlRegion) {
        fUrlRegion = urlRegion;
    }

    @Override
    public IRegion getHyperlinkRegion() {
        return fUrlRegion;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTypeLabel() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHyperlinkText() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void open() {
        PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), null, null, null).open();
    }
}
```

In this way, when we click on "hello" substring, "preferences" page will be opened